# JavaScript getting browsers specific history object

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history

There are lots of articles on Javascript and Browser's [history object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history). But I cant find any useful content anywhere.

How can I get a specific history object, lets say I need 30th history object. How I get it?

for example I have a code to get history

```
var hlist = window.history.length;
    for(i=hlist;i<=40;i++){
        ////???????
}
```

How I get url of each history within the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy reasons the history object is protected.  YOu can go forward, go backward got to X number, but you are not allowed to get information on what it actually contains.